# Выражение и словосочетание

Tags: терминология, словосочетания

В чём разница между этими понятиями?

И как называется набор слов, которые могут оказаться рядом в предложении?

Comment: Причиной этого вопроса было то, что я не знал, как правильно озаглавить предыдущий вопрос. В итоге назвал "точно уверен" выражением, показалось, что так звучит лучше, а как надо, до сих пор не пойму.

Comment: Артем, разница в том, что словосочетание синтаксическая единица. Т.е. выражение может выражено ( простите за тавтологию) любым видом синтаксической единицы - словосочетанием, фразой, управлением.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, понял!

Answer (score 1):

О, а оне - термины?!

Словари говорят, что разницы никакой. Ну разве что выражение свободнее себя чувствует и может не ограничиваться парой слов.

[**ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)... **4.** Слово, фраза, оборот речи. *Общепринятое в. Образное в. Литературное, народное в. Не стесняться в выражениях (разг.;* говорить, пренебрегая вежливостью, пристойностью). *Выбирай выражения! (разг.;* призыв соблюдать пристойность, вежливость).

[СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЕ](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1881-1889.html) - это синтаксическая конструкция, образующаяся на
основе подчинительных связей: согласования, управления и примыкания.

[А также](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95) сочетание двух или нескольких слов, объединённых грамматически и по смыслу. *Устойчивое с. Свободное с.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. также: [Свободные и несвободные словосочетания](http://rustest.edu.ru/rules/sintaksis/slovosochetanie/3191/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
"Точно уверен" - словосочетание, состоящее из наречия и глагола.

Образец словосочетания, обозванного выражением:

[Выражение "литературный язык" бессмысленно с точки зрения филологии пушкинского времени.](http://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37063.php)

Comment: Не термины? А как правильно назвать?

Comment: Может, и термины, просто я к ним так давно привыкла, что уже как бы и обиход... Я бы заменила на "понятия".

Comment: Точно, понятия лучше, изменил. >>>"Точно уверен" - словосочетание, состоящее из наречия и глагола. Стало быть, мне лучше переименовать вопрос в "словосочетание ^точно уверен^"?

Comment: Мне представляется бесполезным требование всегда понимать под словосочетанием "синтаксическую единицу": если для рассуждений нужен термин, можно такое понимание "словосочетания" предварительно оговорить. "Сочетание слов" и "словосочетание" - естественные синонимы, которыми любой волен пользоваться по своему усмотрению. Объединяет (=сочетает) слова тот, кто о них рассуждает по какому-то поводу.

Comment: Почему для рассуждений вне связи с семантикой нужно воздерживаться от одного из вариантов, объявленного термином в каком-нибудь циркуляре? Например, нужно порассуждать о фонетическом аспекте стечения согласных на стыке двух слов - кто может мне запретить рассуждения с использованием здесь слова "словосочетание" вместо "сочетание слов"? А отождествление теоретиками словосочетания с выражением и вовсе вредно: вместо разграничения понятий это порождает неразборчивость, граничащую с языковым дальтонизмом :)